# Ubuntu 17.10 VNC Server

Tags: server, 17.10, vnc, tightvncserver

I am looking for a vnc server for Ubuntu with minimal setup. I’ve tried almost every forum procedure you can find with vino, x11vnc, tightvnc, realvnc. I just need a foolproof vnc setup procedure. I would like to run on startup etc but at this point I just want something to work.

There are too many factors involved that I can think of for why I can’t get things to work to include the display manager, the desktop (gnome/unity/etc[I understand that 17.10 uses gnome but I haven’t verified this]) (also I would like to keep the default desktop whatever it is), something about wayland & x11 (no xauthority), etc

Comment: have you tried teamviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me using x11vnc:

So apparently Ubuntu 17.10 uses GDM3 and/or Wayland display managers thus there is some compat issues with Wayland.

Do the following:

```
apt-get install x11vnc
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd
<Enter Password; Saves to ~/.vnc/passwd>

xauth
<Generates .Xauthority file at /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority>

nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
<Uncomment/Change line to "WaylandEnable=true">

<Logout -> click gear -> select the "Xorg" option>
<Login>

x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
<Or whatever you need>
```

And Voila... Now to automate some things

Comment: If -auth guess doesn't work then point to file at `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`